# Does cobalt support Factory reset mode or API?

Tags: factory, cobalt

I would like to ask the cobalt whether existing factory mechanism or related interface? If not, whether will have a related work plan, thank you.

Factory mode: For example, it will delete all useful info, cookies, and other data, and let changed things to restore the original state. make it the same as when the user first used it. then to restart the application.

Comment: In what case do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no web API to do this, but if you are in control of the implementation, you can just delete the storage and that will cover everything. There are two kinds of storage: SbStorage for user data and Cache storage for cached web resources.

#### SbStorage

For example, if you use the provided file-based implementation of `SbStorage`, it writes to `$HOME/.starboard.<hash>.storage`, so you could just delete that file.

If the platform has a custom implementation of `SbStorage`, then it will depend on the details of that implementation.

#### Cache

Cache files are written to the directory specified by the platform response to `SbSystemGetPath(kSbSystemPathCacheDirectory, ...)`. You can just delete that directory to clear any stored data (right now, only application splash screens are cached there).

Comment: Thank you very much, Whether the file also contains the cache file ?

Comment: In what case, do you want to delete those files? Do you have an "app reset" or something like that in your system menu?

Comment: I updated the answer to include information about the cache.

Comment: Yes, I will implement factory mode on cobalt. thank you for your careful reply.